# Getting valid Datetime such as Month/day/year format

Tags: asp.net, datetime-format

my string is like this "21.05.2013 00:00:00"

but i want like this :  "05/21/2013";
so i used format

String.Format("{0:M d yy}", myObject.StartAt.ToString());

but instead of  this "05/21/2013"  it produce this
 "05.21.2013 00:00:00"

Edited area ----------

i tried below code but it still give wrong format it still give "05.20.2013" instead of  "05/20/2013";

```
  DateTime arrivalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(hotelSearchModel.StartAt.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime departureDate = DateTime.ParseExact(hotelSearchModel.StartAt.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


        request.arrivalDate = arrivalDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        request.departureDate = departureDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `StartAt` a string or a DateTime? If it's a string, you'll need to convert it to DateTime for the formatting to work. Also, you'll need to change your formatting pattern to *MM/dd/yyyy* to get *05/21/2013*:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(myObject.StartAt, "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: StartAt is string and  it still give  wrong format arrivalDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") it produce this : "05.20.2013"

Comment: i edited question wtih your code but it still gives wrong format

Comment: Try `arrivalDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`